# What kind of diagram is best to represent the flow of a registration process?

Tags: registration

For planning What is the best way to visually represent a typical registration flow where a user registers on a registration page, there is then a confirmation page followed by validation email and welcome email, etc?

Comment: Who will be using the diagram? A flow diagram is the obvious answer, but whether that is suitable and what information it should contain depends on the audience.

Comment: See answer to a similar question here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/97122/visualize-a-simple-workflow-content-visualization/132329#132329

Answer (score 2):

Flowchart is the most intuitive way to visualize a process. It is common solution any step-by-step instructions. It also allows to highlight important details: main sequence (path), final steps, etc.

[image]

By the way, this is a standard approach. [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) defines several diagram types, including [Activity diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram):

> Activity diagrams are graphical representations of workflows of
>   stepwise activities and actions[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkdhw.png) with support for choice, iteration
>   and concurrency. In the Unified Modeling Language, activity diagrams
>   can be used to describe the business and operational step-by-step
>   workflows of components in a system.

Some useful guidelines:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the goals of the diagram.  For example:

- If the diagram is for empathizing with the user experience, you might want to consider a **storyboard** or **narrative script**
- If the diagram is to document feature requirements, a **workflow diagram** would probably be more appropriate.
- You may also want to consider something like a **clickable prototype**, which won't visually represent the flow but will *interactively* represent the flow while visually representing the actual screens.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to put a label on what that diagram is called but you are essentially looking to visualize the flow. This can be called a 'flowchart', 'user flow', 'UI flow', or a ux 'use case' (different from a programmers 'use case').

A good example of a flowchart can be found here:

https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/edit/4543-dcc8-5123936c-8c53-10720a005798#?demo=on

And a good article about a quicker way to sketch this out can be found here:

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1926-a-shorthand-for-designing-ui-flows

I don't think it really matters what diagram you use, what is important is that you can visualize what needs to be done and get everyone on the same page. I personally prefer a flowchart because it has well defined [symbols](http://www.edrawsoft.com/flowchart-symbols.php) that create a standardized language to convey the necessary steps for designers, project leaders, programmers, and the likes. Either way, for registration, I think the **conditional** is an important aspect for showing what decisions the user will have to make and where that will lead them. Also remember that some **conditionals** will be decided by logic not the user.